# Настройка собственной библиотеки

Tags: reactjs, rollup

Подскажите, пжлста, собрал свою небольшую библиотеку на rollup, можно ли как то сделать чтобы при импорте компонента не надо было отдельно импортировать стили из nodemodules, а они сами подцеплялись в компоненту. Сейчас это в таком формате
желательно без оверинжиниринга

```
import '@jesyscyclist/lazy-ui-library/dist/esm/index.css'
import { Select } from '@jesyscyclist/lazy-ui-library'
```